# Android studio Material design : Autocomplete not select automatically items dropdown

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm trying to make a menu selectable, the menu works fine but when I try to select an item nothing happens, the menu stays fixed.

I want when I select an element that the value can be automatically displayed on the entry.

Here is my xml file with the autocomplete element :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/order_transfert_amound_fixed_layout"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/transfert_amount"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_monetization_on_24">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/order_transfert_amound_fixed_textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/select_amount"
                android:inputType="none"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Here is the xml file **fixed_amount_list.xml** which contains the layout of my items :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"/>
```

And so my AmountActivity class which contains which allows me to apply the list:

```
public class AmountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AutoCompleteTextView order_transfert_amound_fixed_textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_amount);

         order_transfert_amound_fixed_textView = findViewById(R.id.order_transfert_amound_fixed_textView);
         
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.fixed_amount_list, AMOUNTS);
         order_transfert_amound_fixed_textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    
    private static final String[] AMOUNTS = new String[] {
       "10.00", "15.00", "20.00", "25.00", "30.00"
    };
}
```

The list is displayed perfectly but when I try to select an item, nothing happens.
Does anyone have a solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `focusable` and `clickable` from your `fixed_amount_list.xml` file.